# React Router is giving me a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the react router to create multiple webpages without changing my navbar and all it gives me is a blank page. I have tried multiple things such as a browser router, and switch and neither of them work.

````
function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      
      
      <Router>
      
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/aggrid">Aggrid</Link>
        <Route path="/" component={GhibliModal} />
        <Route path="/aggrid" component={Aggrid} />
      
      </Router>

      
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Well first things first, you need to wrap your whole `App` component with [`<BrowserRouter>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/browser-router), but I from what you said in the question, I would assume you already know that.

Secondly, you don't need the `<Router>` component. [Read here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/router).

From reading the documentation, all `<Route>` components **must** be wrapped in a `<Routes>` (note the 's' at the end) component.

And lastly, I'm pretty sure you cannot have `<Link>` components inside the `<Routes>` component.

Also, the `component` prop is now called `element`, so

```js
<Route path="/" component={GhibliModal} />
```

should become

```js
<Route path="/" element={<GhibliModal/>} />
```

Comment: hey thanks for the advice wrapping  the Browser Router around my app div worked. I didn't know that you had to wrap it like that I actually I had the browser Router inside. My navbar is showing but the rest of my page is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<Outlet />` tag in the components that are loaded by Router.
I usually put it at the end of the JSX:

```
return (
    <div>
        <yourcodehere/>
        <Outlet/>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: hey I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Do you have a <BrowserRouter> component ? Furthermore, the `component` attributes has been replaced by `element`.